# Reportlab - How to add space between words

Tags: python, reportlab

I have a text:

```
elements.append(Paragraph(<font size=10>word1 word2</font>, styleSheet["Normal"]))
```

I want to add space between word1 and word2:

```
word1    word2
```

How I can do this?

Comment: maybe just ' '.join([word1, word2]) ?

Comment: It is not work. It not adding the spaces between word1 and word2

Comment: Looks like maybe you need a `\t` tab character between them.

Comment: Hmm maybe that one sample will be helpfull: 
ptext = '<font size=12>Sincerely,</font>'
Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Normal"]))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 48))

Comment: It also not work. It add one space only

Comment: Then we have space between lines, not between words in specific line.

Answer (score 11):

I know I am a little late on this but adding the html for non-breaking space `&nbsp;` worked for me.

Comment: You helped me . Thank You

Comment: &nbsp; is perfect use for between words inline. But if you want to add more than 1 space before the first word (or character) in one line, you need to have some work around, plain &nbsp; will not do it. My workaround was to add a small white color dot, so &nbsp; was not the first character of the line...

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is an easy solution for it.

As a workaround you could try adding a blank (transperent or background color) 1px x 1px image in your paragraph and scale it to the desired width.

```
<font size=10>word1<img src="../path/to/image" width="10" />word2</font>
```

Another (tedious) solution would be to layout your paragraph yourself with textobjects created by canvas.beginText(x, y).

```
textobject = canvas.beginText(x, y)
textobject.setWordSpace(10)
textobject.textLine("word1 word2")
... (setting other parameters such as font etc.)
canvas.drawText(textobject)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pad_text(text, num):
    text = str(text)
    num = int(num)
    text = text[:num]
    remaining = num - len(text)
    print(remaining)
    if (remaining == 0):
        return '<div>'+text+'</div>'
    else:
        res = '<div>'+text+ ' &nbsp;'*remaining +'</div>'
        return res
```

You can use this.